# Is the set of all strings over $\Sigma$ countably infinite or not?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, counting, uncountability

Let $\Sigma$ be an alphabet. Is the set of all strings over $\Sigma$ (i.e. $\Sigma^*$) countably infinite or uncountably infinite?

Comment: It would be helpful to know the cardinality of $\Sigma$.

Answer (score 3):

$\lambda$, $a$, $b$, $aa$, $ab$, $ba$, $bb$, $aaa$, $aab$, $aba$, $abb$, $baa$, $bab$, $bba$, $bbb$, $aaaa$, $\dots$,

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume your set is $S=\cup_{n\geq1}\Sigma^n$.
Clearly, this set is infinitely large. All that is left to figure out is if $S$ is countable.

Any set with a bijection to the set of Natural Numbers, i.e., $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$, is countable.

*Use the above fact to determine why $S$ is an infinitely large countable set*.